# 552 for lack of money in my website billing account, do I have to create a new billing account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a website ([www.thedataclan.com](http://www.thedataclan.com)) that I have deployed on GCP. However at one point I had no money left in the account and it appears that the site went into 552.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

My payment has been received but it looks like the billing account is closed; do I have to create a new account to start the website again or should I just wait for it to redeploy?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Normally/sometimes, you can reopen a closed billing account. After reopening, update the payment information. If you are using the same card, update the card's code, which will start a refresh of the payment method. Otherwise, create a new billing account and attach it to your project. I organized a series of videos on managing Google Cloud billing and payments: https://videolabs.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/

Comment: Many thanks! It is now active! However I still have a 552 error for my website @JohnHanley

Comment: Now that the billing issue has been resolved, did you restart the VM and verify the VPC Firewall rules are correct?